# ¿Cómo guardar un archivo en la carpeta "Musica - Audio"?

Tags: android, kotlin

Estoy descargando archivos con la libreria okHttp, sin embargo no puedo usar `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory` para guardar el archivo en la carpeta publica "Descargas" ya que `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory` esta deprecado en Android Q, según lo que he investigado, la solución seria usar Media Store, sin embargo no logro adaptar el código para ello.

Importante aclarar que este código lo extraje de un proyecto de ejemplo que encontré en GitHub

```
fun prepareDownload(url:String){
        val request: Request = Request.Builder().url(url).build()
        download(request)
    }


    fun download(request: Request){
        client.newCall(request).enqueue(object : Callback {

            // @Throws(IOException::class)
            override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful) {

                    val file = FileUtils.createFile(
                        applicationContext,
                        "audioName"
                    )
                    if (file != null) {
            
                        val inputStream = response.body?.byteStream()
                        inputStream?.let {
                            file.copyInputStreamToFile(inputStream)
                            inputStream.close()
                          
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    //Handle the error
                }
            }
        })
    }
    private fun File.copyInputStreamToFile(inputStream: InputStream) {
        this.outputStream().use { fileOut ->
            inputStream.copyTo(fileOut)
        }
    }
```

**FILEUTILS**

```
object FileUtils {
  
    fun createFile(context: Context, fileName: String): File? {
        val dir = File(
            context.applicationContext.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC),
            "CustomDownloads"
        )  //esta ruta es la siguiente "/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.app.nameapp/files/Music/CustomDownloads/nameArchive.mp3"
        try {
            var success = true
            if (!dir.exists()) {
                success = dir.mkdirs()
            }
            return if (success) {
                var file = File(dir.absolutePath + File.separator + "${fileName}.mp3")
                if (file.exists()) {
                   file.delete()
                }
                file
            } else {
                null
            }
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            return null
        } catch (e: SecurityException) {
            return null
        }
    }
}
```

Con ese código puede descargar sin problemas los archivos que deseo, sin embargo no se guardan en la carpeta publica de descargas, al contrario están en la carpeta privada de la aplicación, entonces según la documentación no serán escaneadas por ejemplo por los reproductores de música, tampoco se mostraran en la aplicación de galería del teléfono si son imágenes o videos.

Aquí algunos enlaces que reflejan el problema, sin embargo no logro adaptarlos a mi proyecto: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56468539/getexternalstoragepublicdirectory-deprecated-in-android-q/57649669#57649669) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67253065/how-to-save-file-to-external-storage-from-link-using-mediastore) [3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64733499/15156779) [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59103133/how-to-directly-download-a-file-to-download-directory-on-android-q-android-10?noredirect=1&lq=1)

No logro entender como guardar lo que se descargo usando MediaStore
Como puedo hacer para guardar el archivo en la carpeta publica de descargas usando okHttp y MediaStore,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sí, deberías usar MediaStore pero los archivos no deberían ir en la carpeta de descargas. Dado que estás descargando música (al menos eso se deduce de tu código), deberías colocarlos en la colección `Audio` porque ahí lo van a buscar los reproductores de música.

En la [documentación](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/media#add-item) hay un ejemplo de como usar la API MediaStore aunque no está muy bien explicado.

Básicamente debes insertar un nuevo registro en la base de datos usando `contentResolver.insert()` y luego usar la uri que retorna este método para guardar el archivo.

El primer parámetro que recibe es la colección (tabla) donde quieres instertar el registro. El segundo es un `ContentValues` formado por pares columna-valor que contengan la metadata del archivo (nombre, MIME type, ruta relativa, etc).

La colección puede ser `Audio`, `Video`, `Images` o `Downloads`. Y las columnas pueden ser cualquier constante que esté dentro de `MediaStore.MediaColumns`.

Finalmente creas un `OutputStream` a partir de la uri que obtuviste y de ahí en más es lo mismo que venías haciendo.

```
fun InputStream.saveToMusicFolder(context: Context, fileName: String) {
    val resolver = context.contentResolver
    val uri = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
        val contentValues = ContentValues().apply {
            put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, fileName)
            put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC)
        }
        resolver.insert(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, contentValues)
    } else {
        File(
            Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC),
            fileName
        ).toUri()
    }
    resolver.openOutputStream(uri!!)!!.use { copyTo(it) }
    close()
}
```

Este es un ejemplo básico, para una app en produción deberías agregarle el error handling apropiado.

El uso sería así:

```
if (response.isSuccessful) {
    response.body?.byteStream()?.saveToMusicFolder(applicationContext, "example.mp3")
}
```

Si realmente quieres guardarla en el directorio `Descargas` (que debería ser para archivos que no coinciden con las colecciones existentes), simplemente reemplaza `MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI` por `MediaStore.Downloads.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI` y `Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC` por `Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS`

Comment: Funciono gracias,
Podría revisar mi otra pregunta
https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/466219/abrir-archivo-de-carpeta-descargas