# Abrir carpeta "Music/miCarpeta" del explorador de archivos

Tags: android

Estoy intentando abrir la carpeta "Music/miCarpeta" donde guardo los audios que he descargado, gracias a la ayuda en [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/465668/c%C3%B3mo-guardar-un-archivo-en-la-carpeta-descargas)

***Intento abrir la carpeta, no el archivo***

Use lo siguiente para guardar el archivo.

```
val resolver = context.contentResolver
val uri = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
    val contentValues = ContentValues().apply {
        put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, fileName)
        put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC + "/" + "miCarpeta")
    }
    resolver.insert(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, contentValues)
} else {
    File(
        Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC + "/" + "miCarpeta"),
        fileName
    ).toUri()
}
resolver.openOutputStream(uri!!)!!.use { copyTo(it) }
close()
```

**Como Abro esa carpeta.**

Imprimí la uri y muestra lo siguiente `content://media/external/audio/media/2706`
2706 es lo que varia dependiendo de el archivo guardado supongo que es una especie de id que se genera para el archivo.
Puedo **reproducir el audio** usando simplemente

```
val i = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri)  //es la uri que obtuve arriba
startActivity(i)
```

Esto muestra aplicaciones compatibles para **reproducir el audio** elijo una y lo reproduce.

He revisado la ruta donde se guarda el archivo, es la siguiente.

//Así muestra googleFiles

**/storage/emulated/0/Music/miCarpeta/audioName.mp3**

//Así muestra el Explorador de archivos

**/Almacenamiento interno/Music/miCarpeta/audioName.mp3**

Entonces espero realizar algo como

OpenFolder(/storage/emulated/0/Music/miCarpeta/)
o
OpenFolder(/Almacenamiento interno/Music/miCarpeta/)

**Nuevamente resalto que deseo abrir la carpeta no el archivo.**

He intentado lo siguiente

```
val intent = Intent()
     intent.action = Intent.ACTION_VIEW
     intent.type = "audio/*"
     startActivity(intent)
```

Esto muestra en mi caso a **googgleFiles** y abre una sección audio, donde se pueden visualizar todos los archivos de audio.

**Inconvenietes**

No abre mi carpeta "Music/**miCarpeta**" , solo una sección donde se muestran todos los audios del dispositivo.

No aparece el explorador de archivos es decir que pasaría si no tengo instalado googleFile, por ello la necesidad de **abrir la carpeta con el explorador de archivos**

También intente con esto, sin resultados favorables.

```
val path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC + "/" + "miCarpeta"
val uri = Uri.parse(path)
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)
intent.setDataAndType(uri, "resource/folder")
startActivity(intent)
```

[Este tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v8SSPMWsStg) pareciera tener la solución, sin embargo usa  Intent.ACTION_PICK , que es para seleccionar el archivo, yo solo quiero abrir la carpeta donde se guardo el archivo, además que no obtuve resultado la abrir la carpeta, sera por que `getExternalStorageDirectory` esta deprecado para mi "uso Android 10"

Comment: En tu pregunta, dice que el archivo se guarda en la carpeta video, en tu código dice que lo guardas en el directorio música pero afirmas que lo guardas en la carpeta descargas, ¿Dónde visualizas el archivo desde el dispositivo?

Comment: Ya corregí, es en la carpeta "Audio" , en el explorador de archivo selecciono la categoría audio y  ahí se encuentra, además dentro de esa carpeta "Audio" tengo una llamada "DescargasMiApp" , ahí se encuentran los archivos. La ruta que me aparece es la siguiente /storage/emuled/0/Music/Mids/nameFile.mp3

Comment: Bien, entonces, solo para esclarecer tu problema, ¿Quieres reproducir el archivo de audio luego de la descarga o abrir la carpeta en donde se ubica?

Comment: Ambos, tengo una notificación que se muestra cuando se termina la descarga, quisiera que al hacer click se reproduzca el archivo, pero sobre todo necesito que un botón abra la carpeta donde esta ubicado.

Comment: Si tienes dos preguntas deberías crear un post para cada una. Además el código que muestras es para compartir un archivo. No das indicios de haber intentado solucionar ninguno de los problemas. También deberías hacer tu pregunta más clara. Los terminos "abrir" y "reproducir" son ambiguos ya que no se sabe si quieres reproducirlo en tu propia app o en otra. Vuelve a leer [ask]

Comment: Lo siento, tiene toda la razón estaba haciendo dos preguntas, ya aclare mi pregunta, ahora solo es una, y agregue lo que he intentado.
Logre reproducir el archivo ahora solo me falta abrir la carpeta donde lo guarde, espero haber sido lo suficientemente claro. Gracias por sus recomendaciones

Comment: Resumen de la pregunta. Deseo abrir la carpeta " Music/miCarpeta/ " , la cual es donde se guardo el archivo.

Comment: No creo que sea posible. Has visto alguna app que lo haga? Normalmente lo que hacen es mostrar los archivos dentro de la propia, no en el explorador de archivos. Hay quienes han logrado algo parecido con soluciones como [esta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67515474/14487370) pero es un comportamiento no documentado y no hay garantía de que funcione en todos los dispositivos. Aparte tampoco es el explorador de archivos sino el storage access framework

Comment: Realmente nunca he visto algo como eso en alguna App. No es una característica necesaria en mi proyecto, sin embargo me pareció interesando colocar un botón que habrá la carpeta donde se encuentran los archivos. Bueno como me dijo antes " Si no te permite hacer algo, probablemente sea porque no deberías hacerlo " ,  así que talvez no halla algo previsto para ello por algún motivo. Agradezco su ayuda.

Comment: Si alguien llega hasta aquí y solo quiere abrir la carpeta descargas en general, solo tiene que usar lo siguiente. startActivity(Intent(DownloadManager.ACTION_VIEW_DOWNLOADS))  Espero le sirva a alguien.

Comment: @SinneroftheSystem Entiendo que en la pregunta que proporciono de ejemplo se necesita abrir la carpeta descargas, si es así. startActivity(Intent(DownloadManager.ACTION_VIEW_DOWNLOADS) funciona para mi, podría colocarlo como respuesta o seria una respuesta innecesaria o que no resuelve el problema. Talvez no estoy entendiendo bien lo que se quiere lograr pero creo que podría servirle a alguien.

Comment: Te refieres a la pregunta en inglés? Es similar a la tuya, en el cuerpo de la pregunta dice que quiere abrir la carpeta Descargas pero en el título y en el comentario dice que busca una solución que le permita especificar cualquier carpeta. No creo que lo mencionas cuente como una respuesta completa pero puedes dejarla si quieres

Comment: Entiendo la dejare, talvez a alguien le sirva.

Comment: Buena intención pero no te ofendas si no es bien recibida. Por la poca explicación que diste es propable que sea eliminada o movida a comentario.

Comment: Cierto olvide que podía haberla solo comentado, seria lo mejor.